# ¿Que hago con "provider cannot be found. it may not be properly installed"?

Tags: sql, delphi, odbc, pgadmin

Tengo este problema con el **RAD studio 10.2** a la hora de ejecutar un programa que muestra los datos de una tabla en un grid... (si si, muy basico). Trabajo con **pgAdmin 4**

[image: Fail]

No se si esto ayude, ya que estuve leyendo que el problema es con los drivers pero no se que instalar.

[image: ODBC drivers]

El data source que tengo creado funciona con el **postgresSQL ANSI(x64)**, no se si es que lo tengo desactualizado, o algo, idk :( pls help

Comment: Parece un problema con el driver para Delphi de la base de datos postgres. Puede que la versión del driver no es compatible con la versión de la base de datos. Yo buscaría en la documentación del driver que versiones de la base de datos soporta.

Comment: Por favor, como parte de la pregunta, incluye la cadena de conexión que estás utilizando en tu componente `TADOConnection`.